# "They had invited Tim as well as <myself> <me>". — Is "myself" correct to you here or only "me" is correct?

Tags: personal-pronouns, coordination, reflexive-pronouns

the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 1494, example 39i:
**(1)** *Both the local authority and **myself** have gone to the minister*. — I was told [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346122/both-the-local-authority-and-myself-me-i-have-gone-to-the-minister-do) it's incorrect but the textbook says it's correct because we can use reflexives (especially "myself") when we have a coordination ("*both the local authority and myself*" is an example of coordination).

the book says the following examples are also correct:
**(2)** *Ann suggested that the reporter pay both the victim and **herself** for their time*. — correct because "*both the victim and herself*" is an example of coordination
**(3)** *They had invited Tim as well as **myself***. — correct because "*Tim as well as myself*" is an example of coordination

Are (2) and (3) incorrect to you too?

P.S.: I understand we can use "I" in (1), "her" in (2) and "me" in (3).

Here is the excerpt from the book if need be:
[image: override coordination]

---

Update:
At first, a great deal of users told me in [another topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346122/both-the-local-authority-and-myself-me-i-have-gone-to-the-minister-do) that (1) is incorrect. [Here](https://ibb.co/m82hNFk) is a deleted post from that topic where you can see it (I don't know why it was deleted; I asked to recover it).

Comment: Why don't you accept what CGEL says? It makes it very clear that both the overrides and the non-reflexives are possible.

Comment: @BillJ The fact you carelessly read my question is disappointing. Please find the phrase "_I was told here it's incorrect_" and look at the link attached  to the word "here".

Comment: It would have been helpful to provide the passage from the book, or a link to it, with your earlier question. I was curious as to _why_ the author claims that the usage is acceptable.

Comment: @Loviii Do **NOT** accuse me of carelessness. FYI, I **did** look at the linked question. which essentially deals with the question of the acceptability of override reflexives and non-reflexives.; just as this question does.  Now, why do you ask "are (2) and (3) incorrect to you too?"What do you mean by "too".  I asked you in my first comment why are you unable to accept what CGEL says? What is you answer to that question, Are you seriously doubting what CGEL says?

Comment: @BillJ I have a feeling as if we see a different text on the screens... The phrase "_I was told here it's incorrect_" means English native speakers told me that the sentence from CGEL is incorrect. You can see it by following the link I gave. Because of this, I began to doubt if the other two examples from CGEL are correct, and so I wrote "too". I can't understand why this may not be clear.

Comment: So you're doubting the accuracy of CGEL because of what "some English native speakers" told you. If you want to believe them, go ahead, and if you want to believe the authoratative CGEL (where the issue of reflexive overrides is explained very clearly) that's fine too. As a native English speaker and a grammarian I don't see any valid reason why you should doubt what it says. To do so is just wasting our time.

Comment: @BillJ As far as I understand, your reputation allows you to see deleted posts. So you can see [this post](https://ibb.co/m82hNFk) (I asked to recover it). It has a great deal of upvotes. Therefore, I can't understand why it's surprising to you that I began to doubt the CGEL.

Comment: What other people post is a matter for them. To repeat, believe whoever you like, it's up to you!

Comment: "This situation looks like so ridiculous to me that resembles a circus" is not a friendly way to say you disagree. For me, the reflexive works best when it reflects a noun earlier in the same sentence. Ann suggested paying "both the victim and herself" because the pronoun *her* would be puzzling after "Ann." Spoiler alert: The Third Man is the first man, an unexpected twist. So *her* would leave us wondering "Who? Paying a third person?"

Comment: Personally and in standard English, I would never use "Both x and myself" went etc.. As X and I are subject pronouns, the reflexive is odd to my ear. However, people do speak like that. That is probably what those other native speakers meant.

Comment: @Loviii This is a good question and deserves careful attention. Sadly, the content of this question seems close enough to identical to your other question that IMO it should be closed (I haven't voted). If you have new information based on answers you received there, then comment on those answers or edit your question there (without invalidating any of the existing answers). If an answer that you like has been deleted, that's unfortunate, but doesn't allow you to bypass the dupe CV rule.

Comment: @Loviii Also, we don't allow images of text without the whole text in the image description code, which now only reads "override description". This is for accessibility for people who use screen readers and cannot see the image itself. It also doesn't allow searches for text in the words in the image. Please type out the words you think are necessary and format them as a quote, including naming the source.

Comment: @Lambie: Your objections would fall under CGEL's "the target of a good deal of prescriptive criticism".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both examples are a little wordy, but they sound perfectly fine.

Comment: But (1) is incorrect to you, right?

Comment: No, (1) is OK too. It would sound better to say "I", but you can say "myself."

Answer (score -1):

Consider:

> Mr Jones:  You should pay Ann for her time, and me too.
>
> Reporter: OK.Let me ask my editor and I'll get back to you.

When the reporter goes back to his editor, he might well say:

> Mr Jones would like us to pay Ann and himself for their time.

Mr Jones is **not** likely to say:

> You should pay Ann for her time, and myself too.

But he might well have said:

> You should pay Ann and myself for our time.

The editor might ask:

> Editor: Let me get this straight. Does Mr Jones want to be paid for his own time, or when we use Ann's time?
>
> Reporter: I'm not sure. I'll ask him and get back to you.

Followup conversation:

> Reporter: Mr Jones, did you mean that we should pay you for your time if we interview you, or that we should pay you when we interview Ann, in addition to paying her for her time?
>
> Mr Jones. Both.  Pay me for my time if you interview me and pay me when you interview Ann, because you're depriving me of time with her. And you might pay Ann if you interview me, for the same reason, though she might be happy to pay you for giving her a break from me.
>
> Reporter: Ah, I see. Let me check with my editor and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Once again the anonymous downvoter doesn't feel compelled to explain themselves and to point out what they believe to be an error.